# Validate Password in PHP Laravel 5.1 that must contain letters, numbers and special characters

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.1

How to make check that my password contain letters, numbers and special characters using PHP Laravel 5.1?

Comment: |regex:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+$/',

Comment: i found that answer